# after animation done then remove

Tags: jquery, animation

https://jsfiddle.net/gkvjv1z6/2/

I wrote this progressbar function,
I have a problem
if execute off function, but the bar still progress animation how to wait till the last animation done then remove do `target.find('.progressbar').remove();`

```
var progressbar = (function() {
  var target = $('#container');

  var structure = `<div class="progressbar"></div>`;

  var style = {
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': '0px',
    'z-index': '10000',
    'pointer-events': 'none',
    'width': '0px',
    'height': '3px',
    'background-color': 'red'
  };

  var repeatInterval;

  return {
    on: function() {
      if (target.attr('data-progressbar') == '1') {
        this.off();
      }


      target.attr('data-progressbar', '1');

      var el = $(structure).prependTo(target);
      el.css(style);

      repeatInterval = setInterval(function(){ 
        el.animate({width: '100%'}, 1000, function() {
          el.css({
            'width': '0px'
          });
        });
      }, 850);
    },
    off: function() {
      if (target.attr('data-progressbar') == '1') {
        target.attr('data-progressbar', '0');

        clearInterval(repeatInterval);

        // wait last animation done the remove
        target.find('.progressbar').remove();
      }
    }
  };
})();

progressbar.on();

setTimeout(function() {
  progressbar.off();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animate()` method uses the fx queue. You could then use `promise()` interface:

```
target.find('.progressbar').promise().done(function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

### -jsFiddle-